# Clear Bootstrap Modal Form after cancel button is clicked inside Modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I have a bootstrap modal with some inputs that I want to clear  and have the modal close if I click the cancel button. It will obviously reset if I refresh the page but I simply want to be able to enter some data into the form fields, click the Cancel button and have the modal immediately close, then once it is closed click to open the modal again and have the form fields be empty.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog bodyWidth">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Data Point</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-inline" [formGroup]="modalForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(modalForm.value)">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!modalForm.controls['dataPoint'].valid && modalForm.controls['dataPoint'].touched}">
          <label>Data Point:</label>
          <input class="form-control special" type="text" class="form-control special"  placeholder="Enter a data point" [formControl]="modalForm.controls['dataPoint']">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!modalForm.controls['ICCP'].valid && modalForm.controls['ICCP'].touched}">
          <label >ICCP:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control special" placeholder="Enter an ICCP" [formControl]="modalForm.controls['ICCP']">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!modalForm.controls['startDate'].valid && modalForm.controls['startDate'].touched}">
          <label>Start Date:</label>
          <input class="form-control special" type="text" placeholder="Select a start date" [formControl]="modalForm.controls['startDate']" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!modalForm.controls['endDate'].valid && modalForm.controls['endDate'].touched}">
          <label >End Date:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control special" placeholder="Enter an end date" [formControl]="modalForm.controls['endDate']">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div style="float: left;">*All Fields Are Required</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" [disabled]="!modalForm.valid" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
    <button type="submit" (click)="resetForm()" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click>Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'add-validation',
 styleUrls: ['../app/app.component.css'],
 templateUrl: 'add.component.html'
})
export class AddComponent {
modalForm : FormGroup;

 constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
   this.modalForm = fb.group({
  'dataPoint' : [null, Validators.required],
  'ICCP' : [null, Validators.required],
  'startDate' : [null, Validators.required],
  'endDate' : [null, Validators.required]
})
console.log(this.modalForm);
this.modalForm.valueChanges.subscribe( (form: any) => {
    console.log('form changed to:', form);
  }
);
}

submitForm(value: any){
  console.log(value);
}

resetForm(){
 this.modalForm = new FormGroup();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FormGroup` has a method called `reset()`:

```
this.modalForm.reset();
```

You can read more about `reset()` and `FormGroup` itself in [Angular 2 official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html).

Comment: perfect. Works great. Thank you!

Comment: just another quick question...I also have that "Add" button right above the "Cancel" one. If I use the reset() method on that, it resets the form but no longer closes the modal. How can I get it to do both? Thanks

Comment: @Drew13 I edited my post, check it out. If it doesn't work, try changing `id="myModal1"` to `#myModal1`.

Comment: @Drew13 Also, you should change type of your cancel button from `submit` to `button`, it may cause some problems for you.

Comment: hmm.. I tried both. Neither seemed to work. First I put (ngSubmit)="submitForm(modalForm.value);myModal1.hide()" inside my open button tag which didn't work so I left it there and changed id="myModal1" to #myModal1 and that caused the button that opens up the modal to begin with not to work.

Comment: @Drew13 Well, if your modal was closing earlier on submit, I don't see why wouldn't it close now. unless you changed something you shouldn't have. You only added `this.modalForm.reset();`, right?

Comment: Yes, before adding

Comment: Didn't mean to submit last comment. Before adding `(click)="resetForm()"` to my "Add" button tag, the modal would close when I clicked it. But after adding `(ngSubmit)="submitForm(modalForm.value);myModal1.hide()"` to the tag, and then trying `#myModal1` instead of `id="myModal1"` that didn't work either.

Comment: @Drew13 Don't add `(click)="resetForm()"` to your add button, simply add `this.modalForm.reset();` to `submitForm(value: any)` method, right below or above `console.log(value);`

Comment: Not sure if the `submitForm(value: any)` method is actually being called. Code editor shows it as an unused method. I tried both including and not including `(ngSubmit)="submitForm(modalForm.value);"`

Comment: @Drew13 Was your `submitForm(value: any)` method called before you changed anything? Check your console and see if anything is printed there when you click submit.

Comment: @Drew13 Sorry, but I can't solve this problem without looking at your code, you can ask a new question with your current code and I'll take a look there.

Comment: ok it won't let me post for 90 minutes so I will post another question tomorrow and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @Drew13 Just tell me, did your `submitForm()` method print anything in console before you made any of the changes I told you?

Comment: @Drew13 Then you had this problem previously, edits I suggested didn't cause it. It may have something to do with the face that both your button types are `submit`, try changing cancel button's type from `submit` to button. Another thing that might cause a problem is `data-dismiss="modal"` on your submit button. Remove those and then check if anything is printed in console.

Comment: The issue with resetting the form on submit button and wanting for it to close as well is because resetting the form resets the validation. So the form cannot be submitted while it's empty if there is required validation. Setting the form values to a single space after adding the value can take care of that. Then you won't have to reset it.